# Does it matter where I initialize my integer?

Tags: c++, initialization, int, cin

I'm trying to understand something. I'm still a beginner to c++ and I just created this little program where you input a value and it tells you whether it's even or odd. To do this, I made an integer called "result" which takes value, and then does % 2 operation.

However, my first mistake was that I put int result above "cin >> value" so for some reason that messed up the program and the number would always be even no matter what. Then when I put int result below "cin >> value" the program worked like it should. Why is it doing this?

Any help would be appreciated thank you. I apologize if this is a duplicate but I don't know what to search for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Human.h"
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main() {


    int value = 0; // where I input
    cin >> value;
    // if you put int result above cin program changes.
    int result = value % 2;

    if (result == 0) {
        cout << "Even number." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Odd number." << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++, functions are executed line by line. When `int result = value % 2;` is above `cin >> value`, it computes `result` before the user enters in the value. So it's `int result = 0 % 2;`. When you do it after `cin >> value`, `cin >> value` happens first, so `value` is set to the entered value, and `result` is computed off of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code whichever programming language you use runs from top to bottom.
You need to first declare the variable, give it a value and then check for being even or odd.

When you used `cin` after setting the value of `result = value%2;` the compiler used the originally initialized value for `value` which is 0 to compute the value of `result` which will be `0%2`.

That's why you need to use `cin>>value;` before setting `result = value%2;`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful!

Comment: There are plenty of languages where the code doesn't "run from top to bottom". Also there are languages where a statement like `result = value % 2;` actually means that inspecting `result` at any time would return the value of `value` at that time, mod 2

Comment: Can you give some examples ?

Comment: @KalKaraman, [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL) comes to mind, where execution is configuring a circuit rather than running what you've written on any sort of processor.

Comment: @KalKaraman even in c++ you can declare function on the very top of file, but call at the bottom

Comment: @IlyaBursov Yeah, this follows the same concept of top to bottom, that's why you still need to declare it on top.

Comment: @KalKaraman no, it does not run from top to bottom, it is parsed so, but not executed

Comment: Within a function and unless modified by control constructs, it's true. But the restrictions are essential

Comment: @MSalters don't forget about lambdas, like this `int value = 0; auto result = [&value]() { return value % 2; }; std::cin >> value; std::cout << result() << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

C++ read the code top to bottom , line by line. So you will have to int your variable first.I made  a much more simpler version of the program if you want to read it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int a;
cout << "a=";
cin >> a ;

if(a%2==0)
    {cout<<"a is even";}
else
    {cout<<"a is uneven";}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a much simpler version, I just thought I would create an integer for "% 2 == 0" so that if I were to ever use it again, I could just write "result." Instead of the entire "% 2 == 0" but both work great! Plus I don't know where I would ever use "result" again so maybe yours is better. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

When you put `int result = value % 2;` before `cin >> value;`, your program will calculate the result before you put a value inside `int value` via your input.
So your program does calculate `int result = 0 % 2;`